# Impute missing values of time-series with interpolated values in SPSS Modeler with R

Tags: r, spss-modeler

I want to impute missing values of time-series with interpolated values. Since SPSS Modeler only imputes with median, mean etc I tried to impute the missing values using the R-extensions. R requires the package `imputeTS` to be able to impute the missing values via command `na_interpolate`. In R this works perfectly fine, however the package `imputeTS` is not working in SPSS Modeler 18.1 with R version 3.3.0. Is there a workaround or some way I can impute missing values with python in SPSS Modeler?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? If you have a specific error, then add it here. I don't see why it would not work? PS: why don't you process data in R first and then export it to SPSS?

Comment: In the output console of the transformation extension node it says that the package imputeTS was created under R version 3.3.3. SPSS Modeler works with R version 3.3.2.